# How to structure the CN1 code for a tablet form layout?

Tags: codenameone

I've been building my Codename One app for the phone screen format so far. There is a separate Form for the main menu, then a second Form with a list of elements, and then a third Form to edit an element selected from the list. Each Form has an overflow menu and various Titlebar command buttons. And each (Extended) Form has a lot of code that implements the functions in the Form and shares variables etc.

However, to use the tablet (iPad) screen estate, I would like to show the main menu on the left of the screen, the list of elements in the middle and the element edit form on the right. Something similar to the screenshot below. This seems to be a common type of layout on tablets and suits my app usage pattern well.

However, I don't see an elegant way of structuring the code to do this. I can't easily combine the list and edit Forms into one Form, and writing a completely new Form just for the tablet format would be a lot of work. I assume others have faced the same challenge and would love to hear how you achieved this.

PS. I know the side menu can be made permanent but that only solves part of the problem, not how to show a list and edit Forms at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no one answer for this but if you look at apps like [Codename One Build](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-app-on-ios.html) you would notice they adapt to this form factor.

We usually just use `isTablet()` to adapt the UI at key points to the different form factor. One element is the [permanent side menu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html) which we turn on in the init method using code like this:

```
if(Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
    Toolbar.setPermanentSideMenu(true);
}
```

It makes the side menu stay open all the time. Within the code we try to use `Container` instead of `Form`. This allows us to package multiple logical pieces into a single UI for the tablet mode.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I knew about the side menu.

Comment: Any users of CN1 who have found working solutions to this need? I'm surprised CN1 has not had to address this need before, I thought most apps have a dedicated tablet layout that require more than just a permanent side menu and one big form. I was thinking one solution could be a kind of meta-form that can include several other forms, but a bit beyond my expertise :-)

Comment: You are looking for a magic bullet which doesn't exist in any platform. We made a few attempts to simplify this in the past but it looked bad. On native iOS and Android you literally create two completely separate layout/GUI files to solve this issue. There's no magic bullet.

Comment: Yes, a magic bullet would be nice :-). Thanks for the insight. If anyone has an approach they’d like to share it’d be most welcome.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear on how easy it is, see the kitchen sink demo. It has very little code dedicated to support both tablet/phone form factors and the UI looks very different: https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/

Comment: Thanks again, I understood your answer and I am aware of the Kitchensink demo, and isTablet(). However, I think my real question boils down to how to show two Forms on the screen at the same time without having to do extensive rewrites.  Or alternatively, to understand how I could rewrite my existing Forms so the can be used both in tablets and phones, I’d really like to avoid having to duplicate all the code from existing list and element-edit screens into a new tablet-only Form.

Comment: You can add two forms to a parent form. It generally doesn't look good and that's not what you see in iOS. Notice that in the kitchen sink the code isn't duplicate or rewritten. Just abstracted differently. You can see a larger example in the online course if you look at the Facebook Clone app, I used a similar strategy there and even created completely different UX for iOS/Android login to show how easy that is https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java

Comment: Thanks again Shai, you’re incredibly helpful. I somehow had the impression that Forms could not contain Forms, I will try that and see if it can work, of course with some tweaks to the existing forms. About the Kitchensink example, maybe I miss a point, but I can’t understand how it adresses the need to show at the same time. an (editable) list of elements, and a pane to edit the element selected in the list. To me it seems like the simpler case of a fixed side menu and a single adaptable Form for the content (the Dogs pane). So, apart the fixed side menu, same structure as on a phone.

Comment: The needs of that app are simple but it shows the core idea of the abstraction. Instead of deriving `Form` derive a common base class that implements all the functionality you need. Then compose that into forms when running on a phone and into a tablet UI when running on a tablet. That way all your tablet/phone specific code can be concentrated in one place.